# Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, nodemon

I am currently working on a projects that involves making an oracle connecting to an express back-end. The environment was already implemented and pushed to a repository on github. I cloned the project and ran npm install to get all the packages needed for the project. Then I tried to run the project and got this error:

```
module.js:550
   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xxxx\xxxx\Documents\Work\ef-backend\bin\www:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I then proceeded npm install babel-register thinking maybe the package made it into the gitignore. After the package was installed, I tried to run the project once more and continued to get the same error.

Answer (score 26):

I have resolved this issue myself, it was actually an issue with package-lock file being out of sync with the package file. I deleted the package-lock file and npm installed. This then allowed my project to run correctly.

Comment: I have the same issue, after removing the package-lock, which command I should run? `npm install` or `npm install --save-dev @babel/register` ?

Comment: Thanks. This saved a lot of my time.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElmoniem "npm install --save-dev @babel/register" did the trick for me.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: @Matt H Thanks a tone you saved me.

Comment: Work for me with this steps: 1) Delete package-lock 2) Delete node_modules folder 3)npm install

Answer (score 5):

in my case my script had an error:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node --require 'babel-register' src/index.js"
  }
```

I had to edit my script by **removing quotes** in babel-register, the correct statement was:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node --require babel-register src/index.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar issue; Running `mocha` was returning this error:

```bash
✖ ERROR: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/register'
```

**To fix it, I needed to run `npm test` instead of `mocha`.**

The `npm test` script is defined in the `package.json` manifest. Here are the relevant dependencies.

**`package.json`**

```json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "mocha",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1"
  }
```

In the same location as `package.json`, there are 2 other files:

**`babel.config.json`**

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

**`.mocharc.yaml`**

```yaml
require:
    - "@babel/register"
```

**The difference between `mocha` and `npm "test": "mocha"` is that `npm test` uses the `mocharc.yaml` file.** This hint came from the Babel package in the `mochajs/mocha-examples` repository on GitHub.

> *npm test - run the tests using the local .mocharc.yaml config file*

Source:

- [mochajs/mocha-examples packages Babel repository](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/tree/master/packages/babel#commands)

Comment: This is a very complete and insightful answer. It links to the whole world of Mocha configurations, which I found very helpful for solving my slightly different problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you guys are still facing issues please add **production=false** in .npmrc if your @babel/register is in dev dependency
2. I am having the same issues with node 16 and 18
3. Or use **npm install --include=dev**
4. Solve by adding npm config set production false on groovy file
5. if you do not want to do production false use
   **npm config set include dev** this will also work

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did not have a `devDependency` to `babel-cli`. Adding it made everything work fine

Comment: for me it depended on the version, i did not need babel-cli until i installed the latest @babel/register, when i used an old version of it, it wasnt necessary

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10777#issuecomment-559765256 solved my issue:

> Issue was that mocha was in the global installed modules, and not part of dev dependencies

Answer (score 1):

This error could occur due to the mistake of not doing `yarn install` after cloning the repo.