# Running my first truffle file, Cannot find module 'babel-register'

Tags: npm, blockchain, solidity, truffle

I am working on building the marketplace dapp from dapp university on Youtube. While running `truffle compile` it gives me the following error

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'

In this answer: [Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748871/error-cannot-find-module-babel-register) someone suggested that I delete package-lock and do npm install again.

but when I searched up how to delete package-lock,I found this [Deleting `package-lock.json` to Resolve Conflicts quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124033/deleting-package-lock-json-to-resolve-conflicts-quickly/54127283) which pretty much says that "don't ever delete package-lock.json."

I am a beginner, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that some of the dependencies in that source code are outdated.

I avoided this specific issue by running `npm audit fix --force` after `npm install`

I then ran `npm install -g npm-check-updates` to update all of the packages.

`ncu -u` will also upgrade those dependecies directly in the json.

Finally, `npm update`

`truffle compile` should now work as expected.

Good luck in your blockchain development! I'm just starting myself :)